# R / PLM Package: How to include a nested effect for the same brands across countries?

Tags: r, nested, plm, random-effects

I am currently analyzing a panel data set, which tracks brands across countries over time.In particular, I am interested in how certain variables are impacting future market share.

Using the head() function, my data set looks as followed:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 10
   Country Brand Date      MS     uuu     vvv   www   xxx   yyy   zzz
   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 BR      AAA   2015Q1 13.0  46.4    66.7     23.8     9  23.7  613.
 2 DE      AAA   2015Q1 16.1  56.5    35.6     36.5     8  23.7  461.
 3 ES      AAA   2015Q1 15.4  40.9    40.9     27.6     9  23.7  548.
 4 FR      AAA   2015Q1 14.4  48.4    25.1     30.1     8  23.7  414.
 5 IT      AAA   2015Q1 15.0  33.2    33.2     35.2     9  23.7  650.
 6 JP      AAA   2015Q1 14.8  19.6    -5.81    31.5     9  23.7  735.
 7 KO      AAA   2015Q1 14.3  45.7    26.1     42.4     9  23.7  410.
 8 UK      AAA   2015Q1 17.6  40.6    12.7     25.9     9  23.7  660.
 9 US      AAA   2015Q1  3.82 -0.651  -0.651   23.2    11  23.7  429.
10 BR      AAA   2015Q2 14.6  40.4    62.2     25.0     9  23.7  583.
11 DE      AAA   2015Q2 16.9  52.0    30.6     35.3     9  23.7  539.
12 ES      AAA   2015Q2 14.7  41.8    41.8     30.1     8  23.7  558.
13 FR      AAA   2015Q2 15.2  51.7    29.1     30.2     9  23.7  445.
14 IT      AAA   2015Q2 16.9  44.4    44.4     35.5     9  23.7  573.
15 JP      AAA   2015Q2 16.2  20.3    -8.73    29.4     9  23.7  664.
16 KO      AAA   2015Q2 16.0  49.1    31.6     40.2     9  23.7  408.
17 UK      AAA   2015Q2 18.8  34.4    10.2     27.5     9  23.7  788.
18 US      AAA   2015Q2  4.12  0.0770  0.0770  22.5    11  23.7  446.
19 BR      AAA   2015Q3 13.4  43.5    65.6     26.6     9  23.7  624.
20 CN      AAA   2015Q3 14.3  59.9    66.1     48.6     9  23.7  664.
```

Similar to some examples which I could find in here or on other websites, I attempted to use the PLM package in R to analyze the data via a nested random effects regression.

I started writing my code as followed:

`p_crosscountry2 <- pdata.frame(crosscountry2,index=c("Brand","Date","Country"))`

which is pretty much the same as specified in this threat:
[estimate a repeated measures random effects model with a nested structure using `plm()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329807/estimate-a-repeated-measures-random-effects-model-with-a-nested-structure-using)

However, there is one fundamental difference between the examples I could find and my case:

In all examples, each lowest level unit is only linked to one higher level (example: each Student only belongs to one school), while in my case the lowest level units can belong to several higher levels (several brands are present in multiple countries).

When I run the dataframe code, it shows me the following error message:

```
Warning message:
In pdata.frame(crosscountry2, index = c("Brand", "Date",  :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

Looking into the table (using the proposed function), the data structure looks fine:

```
, , Country = BR

     Date
Brand 2015Q1 2015Q2 2015Q3 2015Q4 2016Q1 2016Q2 2016Q3 2016Q4 2017Q1 2017Q2 2017Q3
  AAA      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
  BBB      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  CCC      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
  DDD      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  EEE      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  FFF      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  GGG      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  HHH      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
  III      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
  JJJ      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
  KKK      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
  LLL      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  MMM      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0

, , Country = CN

     Date
Brand 2015Q1 2015Q2 2015Q3 2015Q4 2016Q1 2016Q2 2016Q3 2016Q4 2017Q1 2017Q2 2017Q3
  AAA      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
  BBB      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
  CCC      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  DDD      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  EEE      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
  FFF      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  GGG      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
  HHH      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
```

Using the head() function, the table looks as followed:

```
             Country Brand   Date    MS       uuu       vvv      www xxx     yyy      zzz
BR-AAA-2015Q1      BR   AAA 2015Q1 12.97  46.43449  66.66667 23.79714   9 23.7342 613.1986
BR-AAA-2015Q2      BR   AAA 2015Q2 14.56  40.38156  62.16216 24.96264   9 23.7342 583.3325
BR-AAA-2015Q3      BR   AAA 2015Q3 13.38  43.53741  65.64626 26.59215   9 23.7342 623.8418
BR-AAA-2015Q4      BR   AAA 2015Q4 14.94  42.18077  67.14491 26.05669   9 23.7342 610.7607
BR-AAA-2016Q1      BR   AAA 2016Q1 15.10  46.62681  68.57387 26.93074   9 26.6329 650.2189
BR-AAA-2016Q2      BR   AAA 2016Q2 15.17  48.34142  71.68285 25.15683   9 26.6329 671.1437
BR-AAA-2016Q3      BR   AAA 2016Q3 13.90  49.98002  71.39433 26.26867   9 26.6329 645.4896
BR-AAA-2016Q4      BR   AAA 2016Q4 15.93  50.23791  71.45123 25.62308   9 26.6329 669.8751
BR-AAA-2017Q1      BR   AAA 2017Q1 14.51  50.65138  72.48567 25.49358   9 31.3494 768.1376
BR-AAA-2017Q2      BR   AAA 2017Q2 14.71  50.07792  73.29870 27.33325   9 31.3494 639.0572
BR-AAA-2017Q3      BR   AAA 2017Q3 14.02  50.25853  72.64736 25.06274   9 31.3494 666.7235
BR-CCC-2015Q1      BR   CCC 2015Q1  4.87 -47.35099 -24.83444 57.96842   7  4.7340 613.1986
BR-CCC-2015Q2      BR   CCC 2015Q2  4.91 -60.50955 -41.71975 50.41528   8  4.7340 583.3325
BR-CCC-2015Q3      BR   CCC 2015Q3  4.86 -56.59722 -39.58333 43.69692   6  4.7340 623.8418
BR-CCC-2015Q4      BR   CCC 2015Q4  4.40 -57.38636 -40.62500 45.89061   7  4.7340 610.7607
BR-CCC-2016Q1      BR   CCC 2016Q1  4.34 -46.82131 -27.83505 46.66406   6  4.8588 650.2189
BR-CCC-2016Q2      BR   CCC 2016Q2  4.63 -45.86039 -27.02922 52.84351   8  4.8588 671.1437
BR-CCC-2016Q3      BR   CCC 2016Q3  5.47 -52.37342 -32.27848 62.05175   6  4.8588 645.4896
BR-CCC-2016Q4      BR   CCC 2016Q4  4.82 -43.54067 -24.40191 58.59462   7  4.8588 669.8751
BR-CCC-2017Q1      BR   CCC 2017Q1  5.10 -42.12185 -22.26891 46.53642   8  4.9031 768.1376
```

I would have two questions on this:

1) Is there a different way to define the dataframe properly? I also tried different orders of the same columns but always ended up with the same error message.

2) As a work-around I created a combined variable of country & brand (e.g. AAA_BR, AAA_CN, CCC_BR,...etc) and used this one instead of the brand variable. This version actually allowed me to executed the nested random effects regression. Do you think that this is feasible option or do I run into problems as I don't account for the fact that the same brands are present in multiple countries anymore?

Thanks for your support!

Sven

Comment: Your data `crosscountry2` seems to be somewhat strange (looking at the output) - it should be a flat data frame - is it?

Comment: Hi Helix123, thanks for your answer! I think that exactly this nested data structure is required. It is also explicitly stated in the example in the documentation of the PLM-package. See the bottom of page 88 in here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf

Comment: For `pdata.frame` you specify the nesting with the `index` argument but it cannot handle nested data frames as input. Try to make it a non-nested data frame and then run `pdata.frame`. In the example of the documentation, the input data frame is non-nested.

Comment: Hi Helix123, I added some more context on my data structure to the description. My actual data set is not nested and it only gets a nested structure once the ```pdata.frame``` command is used. Thanks again!

Comment: I do not think the notion of nestedness you have in mind is the same as is implemented for the nested random effects model in `plm` (Baltagi/Song/Jung (2001)).

Comment: Basically, what you are saying is that based on this definition "nested" means that each firm can only belong to one country, correct? Is there a function which allows brands to be part of different countries or should I use the workarround which I have specified under question 2?